# Accept only multiples of 20 (Ex. 40,60,80) on an input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am a newbie to javascript. I need serious help with a form validation using javascript. Here is what i need the script to perform.

When a user fills a form and he enters numbers other than multiples of 20,(Like 40,60,80,100) he should get an alert.

Example: If i enter 45 on an input field, i should get an error like "You have entered an invalid amount."

{else}

Post form.

Comment: Do you have a sample code that's trying to do this but failing?

Comment: You should show us what you have tried and tell us why it isn't adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `%` (modulus) operator

```
if ((+([value of inputfield])||1)%20 === 0) { /* is multiple of 20 */ }
//   ^convert to Number      ^
//                           ^if conversion fails, use 1 for value
//                            (so %-operation will not fail)
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/bXtMZ/) for a simple example

Comment: Could you please help me with a sample code. It would be wonderful. I am extremely sorry for this reply.

Comment: Hi @Shaikat, i have linked a jsfiddle with some sample code. See edited answer.

Comment: Take a look at the link in my answer for the sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Crz/8/

Answer (score 0):

@Kooilnc is correct, but here's a more complete solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/vN3xK/

```
<form name="numberForm">
    <input type="number" name="number" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    // NB: jQuery is required
    jQuery('[name="numberForm"]').bind(
        'submit',
        function(evt) {
            if(jQuery('[name="number"]').val() % 20 != 0) {
                alert('Your number is wrong');
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Can I suggest you use `%` instead of regex, 'cos it's way much neater.

Comment: Please include the code in your answer as well. In case the link becomes unavailable, your answer is useless.

Comment: Good point. I will do that in future. No harm in providing both.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
if($('#input_id').val() % 20 != 0)
{
    $('#input_id').val('');
    alert('You have entered an invalid amount.');
} 
else 
{ 
    //success
}
```